# Line of text in Illustrator has a line appearing between each letter of the sentence

Tags: adobe-illustrator

very new to Illustrator (and StackExchange!), and I just was trying to write some text along a path. For some reason, these lines appear between each letter whenever I type something. How do I fix this!
[image: This is what I'm working on.]

[image]

Comment: Hard to say based on your screen shot. Sort of need to see what the Appearance Panel looks like with the type object selected.

Comment: Hi, just put in a new screenshot

Comment: Appears to be the same screen shot. Still no visible Appearance Panel. (Not the same as the Appearance in the Properties Panel) -- Window > Appearance unless they've REALLY altered things for CC 2020.

Comment: Sorry about that, very new to this! Just added another screenshot which should show the appearance

Comment: Are the underlines part of the type? I mean i would expect that not to work. However if you separate the type form manually done underlines it should work fine.

Comment: I think you've mistakenly applied a fill or stroke to the path the type is on.  That yellow fill **under** the character item in the Appearance panel may be the issue. Try removing that fill.

Comment: I wonder if you might consider sharing a simplified AI file that demonstrates the problem. I just can't replicate it.

Comment: @joojaa is correct Monserrat Subrayada is designed as an underlined font and is showing just as it supposed to- just change your font to regular Monserrat

Comment: Yeah, it was the font, I feel stupid haha! Thank you.